# Upload image file to php server from react-native

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, file-upload, react-native

I am attempting to upload an image file from react native to my php server. My problem is how to post a file object to php.

My javascript code:

```
 storePicture(){
    const file = {
     uri: this.state.selected[0].uri,
     name: this.state.selected[0].filename,
     type: 'image/jpg'
    }


   fetch('http://localhost:8888/s3/index.php', {
     method: 'POST',
     body: JSON.stringify({
       file: file
     })
   })

   .then((response) => response.json())
   .then((responseJson) => {
     console.log(responseJson.status)

   })
}
```

My PHP code:

```
$data_back = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

$file = $data_back->{"file"};
```

Comment: What is the expected behaviour? What is actually happening?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot stringify like that. Try to create a FormData object, append the file to it and add the FormData to body.

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append("image", this.state.fileInputElement.files[0]);

fetch('http://localhost:8888/s3/index.php', {
 method: 'POST',
 body: formData
})
```