# File Uploading in react native to php server

Tags: php, ios, reactjs, react-native, file-upload

I am implementing file uploading in react-native-ios,
Here is my code on react-native js :

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('photo', { uri: image.sourceURL, name: image.filename, type: 'image/jpeg' });
// here is my formdata console :{uri: "file:///Users/.../DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0002.JPG", name: "IMG_0002.JPG", type: "image/jpeg"}
fetch('services.php?action=MultiplefileUpload',{
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    },
    body: formData
  }).then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
     console.log(responseJson);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

And on php page I wrote:`return $_FILES`
Response coming is : `photo: {name: "IMG_0002.JPG", type: "", tmp_name: "", error: 1, size: 0}`

Where am I doing wrong here in my code? I read this link as well: [Upload image file to php server from react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45641291/upload-image-file-to-php-server-from-react-native)

Comment: I don't have an answer but I would suggest you look into [react-native-fetch-blob](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob#user-content-upload-example--dropbox-files-upload-api). It has a loot of functionality and is very popular.

Comment: Thanks To respond, I fixed my issue to solving file size issue. Now I can upload single file on server :)

Comment: can you answer my this post (facing further issues from backend ) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49279477/react-native-multiple-file-upload-using-form-data-returns-single-file-of-array

Comment: Sorry but that has more to do with PHP rather than React-Native and I know nothing about PHP.

Comment: @PriyankaSadh next time you find a solution, do post it as answer below so it helps others. Dont be selfish!