# react-native multiple file upload using form data, returns single file of array from php server

Tags: php, ios, react-native, file-upload

I can upload single image successfully, with this code
[File Uploading in react native to php server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49272339/file-uploading-in-react-native-to-php-server?noredirect=1#comment85547844_49272339)

Now I have to tried sending multiple images (formData append in foreach) to php server, 
I am doing so:- Sending files array to php, But at php side it's taking single last image of array, Can you please suggest me on this, How to retrieve all files of formdata in php sent from react-native.

[Here is the request file form data console image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYdxJ.png)

[Here is the response of single file not getting all 2 files in php console image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRbWF.png)

Comment: This is not duplicate, this question for multiple files, And also there are some backend issues in this question was mentioned, Because sending data on server is correct but returning response is wrong as it returns only single file not an array, Would request to read both question. One more thing in this post I uploaded screen shots as well .

Comment: Hi how did you solve this?